# TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python

so ,in python, when I try to execute the following code.

```
from subprocess import *
args = "A"*99

args = list(args)
args[ord('A')] = "\x00"
args[ord('B')] = "\x20\x0a\x0d"
proc= Popen(["./input2"]+args,stdin=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
```

I get

> TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

So I did some research and realize if there is any integer formatted argument in `Popen()` it will give me the error. But I don't know which argument can possibly be an integer.

FYI: if I comment out

```
args[ord('A')] = "\x00"
args[ord('B')] = "\x20\x0a\x0d"
```

this code, the error doesn't appear at all.

- the programme input2 is written in c which will simply take the input and compare the value - argv['A'] - with "\x00" if true, programme will print out stage 1 clear.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do? Why are you trying to pass those weird command-line arguments to `./input2`? If `input2` is something you wrote, why did you write it to take this stuff as command-line arguments?

Comment: You can't put a null byte (`"\x00"`) in one of a program's arguments.

Comment: it was CTF question on pwnable.kr

Comment: where the value in argv['A'] have to be matched with the value "\x00" 
that's why I'm trying to pass those weird value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more appropriate as a comment, but I don't have enough reps yet. I was going through this challenge and faced the exact problem. Turns out you can simply do a `args[ord('A')] = ""` to avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to `Popen` may not contain the NUL char `\x00`.

For instance this works:

```
Popen(["/bin/echo", "Hello"])
```

But this does not:

```
Popen(["/bin/echo", "Hello\x00"])
```

Comment: hmmmmmm then is there any replacement function for Popen?

Comment: Popen uses lowlevel c function `execv` to run the program. `execv` parameters are strings, c strings are terminated with NUL char, so afaik there is no way to send NUL char as part of an argument using Popen nor any similar functions.

Comment: hmmmm gotcha ty for answer